# JPQL query for entities belonging to another entity and satisfying certain conditions

Tags: java, jpa, join, jpql

I have a `Patient` entity which holds a list of `Appointment` objects. `Appointment` has no knowledge of `Patient`. I would like to create a JPQL query which finds appointments that belong to a specific patient between specified dates. It looks as if I need to write this query inside `Appointment` but since `Appointment` does not have a field of type `Patient`, I am finding it difficult to do so.

Edit (with more information):

I know I have to do it using some sort of join but I don't know much about joins to write the query.

Edit (with links to entities):

[Appointment](https://bitbucket.org/infovillafoundation/ffssclinicapp/src/f49923d7b49b3007d4cfb0f66d48be1cdc8fb8d0/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/infovillafoundation/ffss/patientbooking/db/Appointment.java?at=master)

[Patient](https://bitbucket.org/infovillafoundation/ffssclinicapp/src/f49923d7b49b3007d4cfb0f66d48be1cdc8fb8d0/src/main/java/org/bitbucket/infovillafoundation/ffss/patientbooking/db/Patientbooking.java?at=master)

Comment: Please show the Patient and Appointment entities with the relevant fields and relations.

Comment: Don't post links. Post the code.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need a join:

```
select a from Patient p
join p.appointments a
where p.id = :patientId
and a.date between :start and :end
```

Whe  you don't know much about something, the best way to know more about it is to read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins).